# Why does my powerset function run out of memory?

Tags: python, powerset

```
def powerset(x):
    total1 = [[]]
    total2 = [[]]
    for a in x:
        for b in total1:
            c = list(b + [x[a]])
            total2.append(c)
        total1 = total2 
        # the total 1 and total 2 system should prevent it 
        # from creating an infinite loop when we add to the total.

        print (total1)

f = [1,2,3]
g = powerset(f)
print (g)
```

Here is my attempt at creating a powerset for an intro to data science class. When I run this I receive `[[], [2]]` as outputs before running out of memory. I don't understand why it it returns `[[], [2]]` nor why it runs out of memory, since `total1` is changed outside of the loop.

The variable `g` should return a power set of `f`.

Could somebody explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `for a in x` does *not* iterate over *indices* but over the elements in `x`.

Comment: For a set of size *n*, the powerset is of size 2**n. This is very fast, and will reach a little over 1 billion in as little as a set of 30 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first loop you set `total1 = total2`, so that means that **`total1` and `total2` refer to the same list**.

And so in the second loop, you iterate over `total1` and update `total2`, the same list. In Python (and in most programming languages) it is dangerous to *alter* a collection you *iterate* over, so you keep adding items to the list, making the loop longer and longer.

The code is not per se problematic. We can write it as:

```
def powerset(x):
    result = [[]]
    for xi in x:
        xil = [xi]
        for j in range(len(result)):
            result.append(result[j] + xil)
    return result
```

Although it may look like some syntactical rewrites, we here iterate `j` over the `range(len(result))`. Note that we calculate `len(result)` *only once*, when we start the `for` loop, so after that, we can safely update `total`, since the range object does not change anymore.

This then yields:

```
>>> powerset([1,2,3])
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Notice that we can use the `itertools.combinations` function to make life easier:

```
from itertools import combinations

def powerset(x):
    xl = list(x)
    for r in range(len(xl)+1):
        for ri in combinations(xl, r):
            yield ri
```

We then obtain:

```
>>> list(powerset([1,2,3]))
[(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: This may be out of the scope of the question, but I was under the impression that when you equate the two, they do not update together, I.E. `a=1, b=a, b += 1, print a` prints `1` instead of 2?

Comment: Thats because `int`s are immutable, so Python fallsback on `__add__`. Lists are mutable.